# How to configure if one of the Shopping Cart Price Rule applied Product A no other shopping cart apply for same Product A?

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount

Once the shopping cart price rule applied, remaining shopping cart price rule not going to apply for same products.

Answer (score 0):

set : **Stop Further Rules Processing** to **Yes**

[image]

check below links for complete information :

["Stop Further Rules Processing" not working on coupons?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92536/stop-further-rules-processing-not-working-on-coupons)

http://support.magerewards.com/article/1536-stop-further-rule-processing

Comment: not working..........

Comment: Not working.  My first Condition: Buy 4 pay 3 -> https://snag.gy/GU98nW.jpg second condition : Buy 7 pay 5 -> https://snag.gy/GcLYeC.jpg. if i set set : Stop Further Rules Processing to Yes for my both shopping cart price rule, Buy 4 pay 3 conditions only working.

Comment: yes, it works like that only , once you set `Stop Further Rules Processing to Yes` than only that shopping cart price rule will work[ which one is have highest priority ] , in question also you mentioned same.....